# Carbon Get diffInDays if less than 1 month or get diffInMonths if more than 1 month

Tags: laravel

I want to show days if the range between `date1` and `date2` is less than 1 month, and if it was greater than 1 month, I want to get the date difference in months.

I have a class and function like code bellow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Utility;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class DaysBetweenTwoDate
{
    public function count($start_date, $end_date)
    {
         $date1 = Carbon::parse($start_date);
         $date2 = Carbon::parse($end_date);

         if ('less than 1 month') {
            $result = $date1->diffInDays($date2);
         } else if ('more than 1 month') {
            $result = $date1->diffInMonths($date2);
         }
               
         return $result;
    }
}
```

I know that if I want to get the time difference in days I can use `diffInDays`, and if I want to get the time difference in months I can use `diffInMonths`. But what I don't know is *how to check if the date range between `date1` and `date2` is greater or less than 1 month*?

Comment: Check the diffInMonths first...

Comment: ah... I didn't think of it, thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

What I need to do is simply check result from `diffInMonths` is greater than 1 month or less than 1 month. And if it was less than 1 month, I just need to use `diffInDays` to calculate the time difference in days.

```
<?php

namespace App\Utility;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class DaysBetweenTwoDate
{
    public function count($start_date, $end_date)
    {
         $date1 = Carbon::parse($start_date);
         $date2 = Carbon::parse($end_date);

        $result = $date1->diffInMonths($date2);

        if ($result == 0) {
            $result = $date1->diffInDays($date2);
        }
               
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the condition as you mentioned in your question, like following

```
$result <= 0
```

While using `diffInMonths`, we should get the difference between 2 dates. But the month of "February" has only 28 or 29 days, which will leads a wrong difference between months. So we need to use exact floating difference to get the exact difference in month by using `floatDiffInMonths` method and then need to round the value and convert it into integer as the following code.

```
<?php

    namespace App\Utility;

    use Carbon\Carbon;

    class DaysBetweenTwoDate
    {
        public function count($start_date, $end_date)
        {
            $date1 = Carbon::parse($start_date);
            $date2 = Carbon::parse($end_date);

            $result = (int)round($date1->floatDiffInMonths($date2))

            if ($result <= 0) {
                $result = $date1->diffInDays($date2);
            }
                
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

If in the above case the difference of the `date1` & `date2` is greater than 1 month it will returns the month.

If the result of `floatDiffInMonths` is less then or equals to `0` will checks with `diffInDays` and returns the days between 2 dates.